# How to update mongodb collection and embedded array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

I know this has been asked hundreds of time ... but I can't find anything that works for me.

My query... PUT
`` `http://localhost:8000/api/question/60ccc5031dfd8b1da15f83af ``

The body...

```
{
    "position": "1",
    "question": "If a clerk gave me a shower cap",
    "left": "southpaw"
    } 

My code ... 
    await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.params.id },
    { $set: {updates, answers} },
    { new: true }, (err, result) => {
       if (err) {
         res.send(err);
       }
       res.send(result);
     })}) 
    

Nothing is changed in the database.  Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what was going on, but this works ...

```
const updated = await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.params.id },
    { $set: updates, options},
    { new: true}
  )
      if (!updated) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Question not found with id of ${req.params.id}`), 404)
      }
      res.json(updated)
}
```